# Apache 404 page doesn't show up when it should

Tags: apache

I've had my web server for a while now and known that it was an "apache" server...but beyond that I don't know much about configuring it...but until a little while ago I had it all set up with my own 404 pages...but now even if I try to go to a page on my server that doesn't exist, it will just redirect to my index.php in public_html...any Ideas?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely have a .htaccess file that is configured for use with a PHP framework like Symfony or Zend. In this case, the framework application provides service for URLs that don't actually exist. That is, if your application serves the URL `/path/to/page`, you may not actually have a file named `/path/to/page`. In other words, the framework provides content for the URL without requiring a 1:1 relationship between a URL and a *.php source file. In this case, Apache needs to be configured to send all hits for non-existing pages to a central controller (e.g., index.php) which will then determine what content to serve for it.

Take a look inside your .htaccess file and you'll probably see a few lines like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

If you're not using a framework (or similar mechanism to serve smart URLs) then you can safely remove these lines (or comment them out) to get your Apache 404s back.